# Desktop GUI tools to administer Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, graphical-user-interface

Are there any (Linux compatible) desktop GUI tools to administer Apache2?

Comment: How about gVim? :) Seriously, though - it's well worth your time to work your way through the CLI learning curve. Yes, there will be some frustration while you're learning, but it's a skill that can be incredibly valuable.

Comment: @Erika thx for the suggestion but I've actually been using gVim for some time. My objective was essentially to discover new Apache features that I might not be aware from in a friendly manner.

Comment: Actually, if your goal is to discover new Apache features, I'd recommend against a GUI tool.  By design, they typically focus on the "20% that 80% of people use".  For discovery of cool new awesomeness, I'd recommend going through the config files, blogs, the wiki/documentation, and books like O'Reilly's Apache Cookbook.

Answer (score 1):

[Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) has a module for Apache. Being a web app, it's not exactly a desktop GUI, but it does run on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

[GAdminTools](http://gadmintools.flippedweb.com/) has a httpd tool ([GAdminHTTPD](http://gadmintools.flippedweb.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=45&Itemid=36)), but I'm not sure if it'll do Apache 2, or if it's v1.3 only.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Cherokee Web Server](http://www.cherokee-project.com/) if you would like to administer your web server via GUI.